# How to solve Connect() time-out issues on blocking socket(for SSL handshake)?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

This type of question is(with a lot of variations) kinda answered but.. 
I do need a blocking connect(i'm using SSL)on a socket, that i can set a time-out and maximum number of retries and all that is necessary for never lasting more than t seconds.

I just hope there is some thing i can set in the OS(linux: Ubuntu/CentOS) or some way to do this in code(C) w/o going for an ugly, artificial way like select wait, timeout events added to epoll that close the socket. thank you.

Comment: artificial? why? that's how you do it...

Comment: well, i just imagined this scenario being a pretty common one and that  it should be a simple straight way to do it.. i guess it isn't.

Comment: An SSL handshake *takes* more than a second, in my experience. Setting a timeout that is too short for the event it is timing out is just a waste of your time.

Comment: Your best shot at getting you the "look and feel" of a blocking `SSL_connect` call but with a timeout is to implement your own BIO routines that do `select` or `poll` under the hood to achieve your timeout semantics.

Comment: @ EJP: on this build it takes a bit under 200ms(roundtrip ~ 70ms to the server).. i would never set it too short, i would make it something more than enough, i just mind the 60sec standard timeout..@jxh: thnx, that's what i'm afraid i'll end-up doing

Comment: The '60s standard timeout' is a *connect* timeout, not an SSL timeout. That's infinite unless you set a read timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use alarm system call before and after a connect call and to handle Alarm signal, but this is not the best and most useful way. The better and recommended way is to use a non-blocking socket and use poll or select system calls to handle different stages of making a connection. But if you don't want to use Non-blocking IO your only way is to use alarm.

For a tutorial about using non-blocking sockets refer to : http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=3196

For more information about what happens during a connect call refer to: http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/connect-intr.html